# V8 hidden class index lookup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

V8 use a hidden class to retain an offset of key, so the value of key can be lookup very quickly. But what kind of data structure used to save the offset "map", I read this [post](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html), it use a es6 Map for simulation, but the Map seems use a hash table,  kinda of slow, right?

Comment: You should read through the post. It implemented an alternative offset map without hash table

Comment: I do not think so, it use a ES6 Map for offset map in a hidden class

Comment: You mistaken property access and hidden class access. `CompileNamedLoadFastProperty` uses offset, not hash table

Answer (score 0):

> the Map seems use a hash table, kinda of slow, right?

Nope. Hash tables are kinda fast, and even better: Inline caches (which you were reading about) are all there to eliminate the need for this lookup completely.

Comment: Can I say the es6 Map does not create a hidden class ? But how can it retain a fixed structure ? Any resources ?